# Create Azure container instance with VNet using C#

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-container-registry, azure-container-instances

I have the following powershell command that creates an Azure container group with 1 container instance:

```
az container create \
-g $(ResourceGroup) \
--name $(ContainerName) \
--image $(DockerImage) \
--cpu 2 --memory 8 \
--restart-policy OnFailure \
--vnet $(VNet) \
--subnet $(VNetSubnet) \
--registry-username $(RepositoryUserName) \
--registry-password $(RepositoryPassword)
```

I'm trying to do the same using the .NET Client Libraries, based on this [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aci-dotnet-create-container-groups):

```
var containerGroup = _azure.ContainerGroups
          .Define(agentName) 
          .WithRegion(resourceGroup.Region)
          .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup.Name)
          .WithLinux()
          .WithPrivateImageRegistry("xxx.azurecr.io", "xxx", "xxx")
          .WithoutVolume()
          .DefineContainerInstance(agentName)
              .WithImage(args.DockerImageName)
              .WithExternalTcpPort(80)
              .WithCpuCoreCount(args.CpuCoreCount)
              .WithMemorySizeInGB(args.MemorySizeInGB)
          .Attach()
          .WithTags(tags)
          .WithRestartPolicy(ContainerGroupRestartPolicy.Always)
          .CreateAsync()
```

But I can't find a way to set the vnet and subnet. How to do it using C#?

Comment: I'd say you need to use network profile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.containerinstance.models.containergroup?view=azure-dotnet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.containerinstance.models.containergroup.networkprofile?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_ContainerInstance_Models_ContainerGroup_NetworkProfile

Comment: I still don't understand how to set the network profile using the fluent API, I have the impression it's not possible to do it with the current version - but thanks anyway @4c74356b41.

Comment: yeah, i didnt use c# sdk, so cant really help

Comment: Any more update?

Comment: two years left - still not possible
(c) Microsoft

Comment: @cortisol FYI we stopped using ACI, we moved all our containers to AKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but it seems there you cannot do that through C#. Maybe because it is just a preview version of [Azure Container Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet). You can see all that you can define in [The entirety of the Azure Container Instance service container group definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.containerinstance.fluent.containergroup.definition.idefinition?view=azure-dotnet).

Or you can create it through Azure REST API. See [Container Groups - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containergroups/createorupdate) and you can config the property networkProfile to make the container group in a vnet.

Comment: Thanks @charles-xu, it seems I have no other option than using the Azure REST API.

Comment: I'm still exploring other possibilities before accepting any answer, but thanks anyway for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

**VNET is meanwhile supported**

Add WithNetworkProfile

```
var containerGroup = _azure.ContainerGroups
          .Define(agentName) 
          .WithRegion(resourceGroup.Region)
          .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup.Name)
          .WithLinux()
          .WithPrivateImageRegistry("xxx.azurecr.io", "xxx", "xxx")
          .WithoutVolume()
          .DefineContainerInstance(agentName)
              .WithImage(args.DockerImageName)
              .WithExternalTcpPort(80)
              .WithCpuCoreCount(args.CpuCoreCount)
              .WithMemorySizeInGB(args.MemorySizeInGB)
          .Attach()
          .WithTags(tags)
          .WithRestartPolicy(ContainerGroupRestartPolicy.Always)
          .WithNetworkProfile(subscriptionId,resourceGroup,"aci-network-profile-vnettest-containersubnet")
          .CreateAsync()
```

The profile can be obtained with the e.g. Azure CLI

```
az network profile list
```